# Changing indexing of a matrix in R

Tags: r, matrix, indexing

Can someone tell me, if there is a way of changing the indexing of a matrix. So if i am running a loop, the new index is applied. In my example i would have to change the indexing, so that the index of the matrix is not 1:5 but 64:68. Is this possible.

Thanks in advance

```
a <- matrix(1:20, ncol=4)

a
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    6   11   16
[2,]    2    7   12   17
[3,]    3    8   13   18
[4,]    4    9   14   19
[5,]    5   10   15   20
```

In this case, the matrix index should start with number 64.

My intended result would be:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[64,]    1    6   11   16
[65,]    2    7   12   17
[66,]    3    8   13   18
[67,]    4    9   14   19
[68,]    5   10   15   20
```

So if I apply

```
a[64,]
```

my result would be

```
[64]  1  6 11 16
```

Comment: No, that's not possible (at least not without lots of hackery) and I don't understand why you think you need that. However, you could give the rows names (which would be characters).

Comment: This is a highly not-recommended approach to indexing in **any** language. If you can tell us what the actual problem at hand is, we can most likely suggest an appropriate method.

Comment: Or you could have a matrix with 68 rows and set `NA` to all the elements in rows 1 to 63 and copy `a` to row 64-68, if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you **really** need this (although I agree that it would be better to describe the context in more detail to see if there is an alternative way to do what you want), you could look at the `Oarray` package:

```
library(Oarray)
```

Note you have to use `dim` rather than `ncol`, `nrow`:

```
(a <- Oarray(1:20, dim=c(5,4),offset=c(64,1)))
##       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
## [64,]    1    6   11   16
## [65,]    2    7   12   17
## [66,]    3    8   13   18
## [67,]    4    9   14   19
## [68,]    5   10   15   20
```

Indexing works:

```
a[64,]
## [1]  1  6 11 16
```